# React Native: Image with 100% height

Tags: image, react-native, aspect-ratio

I have an image that should always take 100% of the parent size. The width should adjust accordingly to maintain the aspect ratio of the image. The width can be smaller or larger than the parent. The height must be equal to the parent size.

```
<View style={{height: 220}}>
  <Image source={{uri: 'myuri.jpg'}} style={{height: '100%, ...?}} />
</View>
```

I only find solutions where the width is fixed and the height adjusts dynamically. I want it the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

You can get the application window's width and height using the following code:

```
<View style={{height: Dimensions.get("window").height}}>
  <Image source={{uri: 'myuri.jpg'}} 
         style={{
               height: Dimensions.get("window").height*0.5,
               width: Dimensions.get("window").width
               }} 
        />
</View>
```

Using this way you can proportion the size you want.

You can also review the document here.
[Dimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions)

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but I can't set a fixed aspect ratio. Images might have different aspect ratios.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<View style={{height: 220}}>
  <Image source={{uri: 'myuri.jpg'}} style={{height: '100%, width: 'auto'}} />
</View>
```

Also `resizeMode: 'contain'` can helps you a lot.

Reference that might helps you: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode